# Unknown computer called ATP on my network

Tags: networking

There is a 'computer' which shows up on the network with the name ATP.  I thought it was the disk attached to my router, but couldn't log in with any of my usual passwords and atp is not in my password manager.  I have changed the password to my router disk, but without success.

How can I find out more about the mysterious ATP/atp from my Mac, from my Ubuntu machine or from my wife's Windows machine? An IP address would be useful but I don't find it with arp -a or any other programs I used to use when I was active in a Unix/Mac/Windows environment.

Comment: What type and brand of router do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can log into your router and learn about the IP and MAC address of the "mystery" device, at least.

You could also search the MAC address for the manufacturer (I am not sure how useful is that for you).
Note that it could be faked.

Using its IP you could try accessing the device, depending on what it is.
If it is a hard drive, you may try mounting its partitions.
If it is a computer, you could try `ssh`ing to it, `xrdp`ing.
That very much depends on your case.
A lot of information is missing.
Please make an effort and provide more info.

What do you see in the webpage for the devices connected to your router?

Are you certain ATP is your disk?

Do you have physical access to the disk?

How did you format it? (MBR/GPT, partition types, EFI boot, etc.)

Comment: Mitch, it is a Huawei B525s

Comment: Tejas, I want to know where this entity is and how to log in.  I have now removed the disk from the router and I can no longer try to log in to it when I click Connect, so I assume the disk I removed from the router is the one appearing in my network as atp or ATP depending on the machine I try to connect from.  I have now reconnected the disk to the router and  can attempt to log in, but the new password is rejected.

Comment: Sancho, I know the IP address of the router, and I can get the MAC address from the label on the back.  What I can't do is find a way to login so I can read (and write) the disk.  This is my only disk which is connected 24/7.

Comment: @Deltagande The default username/password should also be printed somewhere. If you changed those (as you should) then you should know. There's always the possibility of resetting it to factory defaults and go from there.

Comment: I was referring to the IP + MAC of the mystery device, not the router. Please see edited answer.

Comment: ChanganAuto, thanks.  I have changed the password though I have left the user the same.

Comment: Sancho, it is the IP and/or MAC address of the mystery computer which I am trying to find.

Comment: @Deltagande - Please see edited answer and provide expanded info, by editing your question, not in comments. Add screen captures (pasted in the question, or linked if that is not possible) if that helps.

Comment: All, thanks for your help.  I have now checked for info on a new Windows computer which tells me that ATP is my Huawei router.  I have (long ago) created two logins to the smb server, and it is on one of these which I have changed the password.  But my Mac still tells me that my user/password is wrong when I try to log in.  I just tried with the user/password to the router itself with no success.  :(

Comment: @Deltagande - Great. If you have problems logging into your router, you can always reset it to factory defaults and use the factory username/password. They are often posted in an attached tag... Now I see ChanganAuto mentioned this.

Comment: I have now established beyond reasonable doubt that ATP is the disk attached to my router.  I have connected it to my Linux machine and my Mac and can read it without problems.  I am now going to consult the manual for the Huawei router and see if there is any secret to connecting to the disk.